# How to respond if iOS update breaks my app?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm new to iOS development, and my problem is that the latest iOS update (8.0.2 at the time of writing this) causes my app not to work properly. My app is already for sale in the app store, so any user who has already upgraded to the newest iOS version is downloading a broken app. I have a plan for fixing the bug, but the turnaround time for new releases is quite slow, and I don't want to screw over all the new users while I wait for the updated app to get approved.

What should I do?

I know I can set the "Deployment Target" in Xcode, but this does not seem to prevent users with the newer iOS from still buying it.

Comment: You just have to fix the app with regard to the latest version. You can take the app off the market in the meantime. This is in fact what we did with out commercial Golf game when iOS 8 broke it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about publishing and not programming.

Comment: You should either find a way to expedite your release, or remove your app from the app store until you can release a working version. Obviously, the former is preferable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Today:**

1. Fix your app as quickly as possible (that turnaround is only about
   you)
2. Submit it to Apple
3. [Request an expedited review request review to Apple](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/contact/?topic=expedite), explaining why you need a quick turnaround (critical bug fix is a valid reason). You can't abuse of expedited reviews, so use them carefully.

**In the future:**

Before Apple releases a newer iOS version, they release developer previews. You need to use these to make sure your app will run smoothly when the newer iOS is released to the public.

Comment: Where might someone go to submit an Expedited Review Request?  I had no idea that that was a thing.

Comment: @admdrew Thanks! I also had no idea there was way to request expedited review.